# FHIR search multiple words with _content

Tags: hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir, hapi-fhir

I am trying to search multiple words using _content search parameter but it  does not work.

Example CAll - GET [base]/Condition?_content=(bone OR liver) and metastases

This request should return all Condition resources with the word "metastases" and either "bone" or "liver" in the entire resource content.

Any help on how to search with _content along with logical operations such as AND, OR etc. would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your tags imply this is a hapi question - better to ask this one on the HAPI support forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Condition?_content=bone,liver&_content=metastases

"," gives or and & gives and.  There's no support for brackets unless you use _filter, which gives you a whole query language, but isn't yet widely supported.

Comment: actually, this is a special case. What the spec says about this parameter is that how it is interpreted is up to the implementer - and the one above is given as a possible example